# w2ui grid: preserve selection on search

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I have a w2ui grid as following:

```js
$('#myGrid').w2grid({
    name   : 'myGrid',
    columns: [
        { field: 'fname', text: 'First Name', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'lname', text: 'Last Name', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'email', text: 'Email', size: '40%' },
        { field: 'sdate', text: 'Start Date', size: '120px' },
    ],
    show: {
                toolbar: true,
                selectColumn: true
        },
    records: [
        { recid: 1, fname: 'John', lname: 'Doe', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 2, fname: 'Stuart', lname: 'Motzart', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 3, fname: 'Jin', lname: 'Franson', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 4, fname: 'Susan', lname: 'Ottie', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 5, fname: 'Kelly', lname: 'Silver', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 6, fname: 'Francis', lname: 'Gatos', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 7, fname: 'Mark', lname: 'Welldo', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 8, fname: 'Thomas', lname: 'Bahh', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 9, fname: 'Sergei', lname: 'Rachmaninov', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' }
    ],
    searches: [
                { field:'fname', label:'fname', type:'text', operator:'contains' },
                { field:'lname', label:'lname', type:'text', operator:'contains' },
            ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/w2ui@2.0.0/w2ui-2.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/w2ui@2.0.0/w2ui-2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id='myGrid' style='height:500px'></div>
```

and I can manually select certain records:
[image: fdsa]

The problem that I have is that when I search some specific values, the previously selected records become unchecked:

[image]

(in this example the record 'Francis Gatos' became unchecked searching for 'an' string).

Is there a way to preserve selection once I apply a search condition?

Comment: Hey, I am also working on the same feature. Currently able to retain the selected IDs but when i try to render them (for 10k records , 3k selected) I run into another trouble , on re-render only 100-200 are fetched rest are unselected again...

Answer (score 0):

The w2ui source code is very clean. You can find the 'search' and 'searchReset' functions of the grid element easily, it looks like this is where the selection is removed. Look for this line in the library file (I use the es6 version of the library), you should find it in both functions:

```
this.last.selection.indexes = []
```

Comment out or delete this line. As far as I've tested it doesn't have any side effects.